# How to add a new type of calendar to using by Windows?

Tags: windows, api, calendar, globalization

There are many type of calendars that use in the world. Below link is the list of these calendars:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars

Microsoft dosent provide all type of calendars in the Windows.

Which API should I use to add a new type of calendar to using by Windows? (May be something like drivers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no provision for user extensible calendars in Windows. Your only option is to create your own support for the given calendar.